# Javascript object properties and functions

Tags: javascript, oop, object

In JavaScript I see a few different ways, certain tasks can be performed within an object for example, the object Egg I have below.

Can anyone tell me the difference between each one, why I would use one and not the other etc

```
 var Egg = function(){

    //Properties

    var shell = "cracked" // private property 

    this.shell = "cracked" // public property

    shell: "cracked" // what is this??

    //functions

    function cook(){

        //standard function
    }

    cook: function(){
        //what kind of function is this?
    }

    //not sure what this is

    details: {
        //What is this? an array :S it holds 2 elements?
        cost: 1.23,
        make: 'Happy Egg';
    }




}
```

Comment: **Q:** What is `shell: cracked // what is this??` **A:** An error!

Comment: What you've quoted there isn't valid JavaScript syntax. It's close, but it's not. For one thing, `var Egg = function() { ... };` creates a *function* and assigns it to `Egg`. Functions are objects, but I don't think that's what you meant by "...the object Egg I have below..."

Comment: @epascarello: Actually, not an error. A [label](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12). Still probably not what he wanted, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know just like the wonderful `javascript:` added by millions of people to event handlers. That line does nothing other than add some bytes to the function. :)

Comment: @epascarello: If it even does that, on a decent engine. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, Ben.

This sort of gets to the bottom of the dynamism of JavaScript.
First, we'll look at basics -- if you're coming from a place where you understand class-based languages, like, say, Java or C++/C#, the one that is going to make the most sense is the constructor pattern which was included very early on:

```
function Egg (type, radius, height, weight) {
    // private properties (can also have private functions)
    var cost = (type === "ostrich") ? 2.05 * weight : 0.35 * weight;

    // public properties
    this.type = type;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.height = height;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.cracked = false;

    // this is a public function which has access to private variables of the instance
    this.getCost = function () { return cost; };
}

// this is a method which ALL eggs inherit, which can manipulate "this" properly
// but it has ***NO*** access to private properties of the instance
Egg.prototype.Crack = function () { this.cracked = true; };


var myEgg = new Egg("chicken", 2, 3, 500);

myEgg.cost; // undefined
myEgg.Crack();
myEgg.cracked; // true
```

That's fine, but sometimes there are easier ways of getting around things.
Sometimes you really don't need a class.

What if you just wanted to use one egg, ever, because that's all your recipe called for?

```
var myEgg = {};  // equals a new object
myEgg.type = "ostrich";
myEgg.cost = "......";
myEgg.Crack = function () { this.cracked = true; };
```

That's great, but there's still a lot of repetition there.

```
var myEgg = {
    type : "ostrich",
    cost : "......",
    Crack : function () { this.cracked = true; }
};
```

Both of the two "myEgg" objects are exactly the same.

The problem here is that EVERY property and EVERY method of myEgg is 100% public to anybody.

The solution to that is immediately-invoking functions:

```
// have a quick look at the bottom of the function, and see that it calls itself
// with parens "()" as soon as it's defined
var myEgg = (function () {
    // we now have private properties again!
    var cost, type, weight, cracked, Crack, //.......

    // this will be returned to the outside var, "myEgg", as the PUBLIC interface
    myReturnObject = {
        type : type,
        weight : weight,
        Crack : Crack, // added benefit -- "cracked" is now private and tamper-proof
        // this is how JS can handle virtual-wallets, for example
        // just don't actually build a financial-institution around client-side code...
        GetSaleValue : function () { return (cracked) ? 0 : cost; }
    };

    return myReturnObject;
}());

myEgg.GetSaleValue(); // returns the value of private "cost"
myEgg.Crack();
myEgg.cracked // undefined ("cracked" is locked away as private)
myEgg.GetSaleValue(); // returns 0, because "cracked" is true
```

Hope that's a decent start.

Answer (score 6):

Your code snippet isn't quite valid, but here are a few things it raises:

### Property initializers, object initializers

You've asked what `shell: cracked` is. It's a *property initializer*. You find them in [*object initializers*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) (aka "object literals"), which are written like this:

```
var obj = {
    propName: "propValue"
};
```

That's equivalent to:

```
var obj = {};
obj.propName = "propValue";
```

Both of the above create an object with a property called `propName` which has a string value `"propValue"`. Note that `this` doesn't come into it.

### Functions

There are a couple of places where functions typically come into it vis-a-vis objects:

#### Constructor functions

There are *constructor functions*, which are functions you call via the [`new` operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2). Here's an example:

```
// Constructor function
function Foo(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

// Usage
var f = new Foo("Fred");
```

Note the use of the keyword `this` in there. That's where you've seen that (most likely). When you call a constructor function via `new`, `this` refers to the new object created by the `new` operator.

`this` is a slippery concept in JavaScript (and completely different from `this` in C++, Java, or C#), I recommend these two *(cough)* posts on my blog:

- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)
- [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)

#### Builder/factory functions

You don't have to use constructor functions and `new`, another pattern uses "builder" or "factory" functions instead:

```
// A factory function
function fooFactory(name) {
    var rv = {}; // A new, blank object

    rv.name = name;

    return rv;
}

// Usage
var f = fooFactory("Fred");
```

### Private properties

You mentioned "private" properties in your question. JavaScript doesn't have private properties at all (yet, they're on their way). But you see people simulate them, by defining functions they use on the object as *closures* over an execution context (typically a call to a constructor function or a factory function) which contains variables no one else can see, like this:

```
// Constructor function
function EverUpwards() {
    var counter = 0;

    this.increment = function() {
        return ++counter;
    };
}

// Usage:
var e = new EverUpwards();
console.log(e.increment()); // "1"
console.log(e.increment()); // "2"
```

(That example uses a constructor function, but you can do the same thing with a factory function.)

Note that even though the function we assign to `increment` can access `counter`, nothing else can. So `counter` is effectively a private property. This is because the function is a closure. More: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Good answer T.J., I'm just missing the explanation about `labels`. Its totally valid to write `shell: 'cracked'` anywhere outside an object literal, even if it makes so sense at this point (if no loop is invoked)

Comment: @jAndy: LOL! Quite true, quite true -- I think I'll leave it out, though, as I'm sure the OP wasn't trying to use a label there... :-)

Comment: well, my point was, if `cracked` is a declared variable, the answer to this question "what is this", would be "a label", for his `shell: cracked` line :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing syntaxes between object property declaration and simple javascript statements.

```
// declare an object named someObject with one property
var someObject = {
    key: value
};

// declare an anonymous function with some statements in it
// and assign that to a variable named "someFunction"
var someFunction = function () {
    // any javascript statements or expressions can go here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a key distinction in JavaScript between objects and functions. Objects hold a bunch of data (including functions), and functions can be used to make or modify objects, but they aren't inherently the same thing. OOP in JavaScript is based around using functions as classes. For example, take the following class:

```
Test = function(){
    this.value = 5;
}
```

If you just call the function `Test()`, then nothing will happen. Even if you say `var x = Test()`, the value of x will be `undefined`. However, using the `new` keyword, magic happens! So if we say `var x = new Test()`, then now the variable `x` will contain a Test object. If you do `console.log(x.value)`, it would print 5.

That's how we can use functions to make objects. There's also a key different in syntax--a function can contain any sort of JavaScript block you want, whether that's if statements or for loops or what have you. When declaring an object, though, you have to use the `key: value` syntax.

Hope that clears things up a little bit!

Comment: Functions are objects that can be invoked! `function(){} instanceof Object === true`

Comment: Not by the technical JavaScript, definition. If they were objects, then `typeof function(){}` would print "object", however there is a separate classification for functions (hence it prints "function").

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function says "Every function in JavaScript is actually a Function object." that inherits from Object.

Comment: Sorry to get pedantic about this!

Comment: @Will: By the technical JavaScript definition, functions are objects. It's not some kind of side thing, it's an explicit, intentional, and core part of the language. `typeof` says "function" because it's being more precise about the kind of object than "object", not because they *aren't* objects. The definition of the word [`function`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.24) in the spec clearly says they're objects, and it's also clear from sections like *"[§13.2 - Creating Function Objects](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)"*.

Comment: @JamundFerguson: And you thought ***you*** got pedantic. :-) (Sorry, Will, *perhaps* a bit OTT there...)